# Oracle top-N query to get number of rows assign an increasing number to each row in the STUD table after sorting by dClass DESC

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying with Oracle top-N query to get number of rows assign an increasing number to each row in the STUD table after sorting by dClass DESC.

```
select studName, dClass,row_number() over (order by dClass desc) rn
from STUD where row_number() over (order by dClass desc) <= 3 order by dClass desc;
```

Below is the ERROR

```
ERROR at line 6:
ORA-30483: window  functions are not allowed here.
```

Here, What change i have do get the records.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a subquery to restrict based on the row number you assign:

```
SELECT studName, dClass
FROM
(
    SELECT studName, dClass, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY dClass desc) rn
    FROM STUD
) t
WHERE rn <= 3
ORDER BY dClass DESC;
```

The reason for the error is that the `WHERE` clause is applied before the row number in the `SELECT` clause has even been computed.  In other word, it is not yet available, but wrapping with a subquery gets around this problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Oracle 12c, this can be done using `FETCH FIRST n ROWS ONLY`

```
SELECT studName, dClass
       FROM STUD
   ORDER BY dClass DESC
FETCH FIRST 3 ROWS ONLY;
```